# post gate level simulation in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, modelsim

I'm trying to make a post gate level simulation for a pipelined processor.
I have the net list in vhdl format and I need now to simulate it again to be sure the functionality is right after the synthesis.
The problem is I have a 2 rams one for instructions and the other for data, in post gate level simulation I don't have the ability to view the memory list view and load my instructions and data into my 2 rams.
How can I insert my data into the rams as they have been translated into flip flops and muxs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607812/initializing-memory-in-netlist-vhdl/16622869#16622869

Answer (score 0):

From your description I would assume that the two RAMs are for instruction cache and data cache.  Since these are usually of a significant size, even on smaller processors, I would doubt that these RAMs are implemented in flip flops and muxes.  My first suggestion would therefore be that you check the netlist to see if the RAMs are actually separate RAM primitive modules.

The reason is that RAM primitive modules may sometimes (depending on model) be initialized with the contents of a file.  In that case you just need to make a file with the right format.

An alternative if RAM primitive modules are actually in the netlist, but don't allow initialization, is to substitute the RAM primitive modules with your own version that can be initialized.

If the RAMs are actually converted to flip flops and muxes, then the processor may support some cache manipulation instructions, usually available from protected (kernel) mode.  These instructions can be used to load the instruction cache and data cache with contents provided by the executed program.  Loading the cache RAMs in this way may take numerous instructions, thus some simulation time.

Last, you may consider not to spend that much time on gate level simulation.  It may be OK to run a little, just to be sure that the netlist is OK, but commercial well known synthesis tools are generally of a high quality, so these are unlikely to be the reason for bugs in your design.  The risk of bugs is much larger in the dedicated design for the project, so you may want to spend more time on functions verification and code review ;-)